# Deserializing JSON in Windows Phone 7 with Json.NET

Tags: c#, silverlight, json, windows-phone-7, json.net

I know that there are countless questions about this. I've read many of them, but to little understanding. Can you help clarify the process of deserializing JSON in WP7?

I've got JSON that looks like this:

```
{ 
    "status" : {
        "code" : 99 ,
        "message" : "Already checked in" 
    },

    "response" : {
        "token" : "faisdufhdaisuflasdkf",
        "distance" : 20,
        "angle" : 45
    }   
}
```

I am trying to use Json.NET, but this is where my understanding is pretty much naught.

```
 var deserializedJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, <TYPE> >>(JsonString);
```

For `<TYPE>`, how can I best define my expected deserialized object? Status and Response as separate classes? Or just one generic all-encapsulating ServerResponse class?

Also, how do I know that this serializer will assign the correct output to the correct class member variables? if I have

```
class Status {
    string code;
    string message;
}
```

How do I know those will be assigned properly?

Thanks. Apologies if this seems trivial. This is my very first project in C#, Silverlight, Windows Phone 7, and/or .NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{ 
    "status" : {
        "code" : 99 ,
        "message" : "Already checked in" 
    },

    "response" : {
        "token" : "faisdufhdaisuflasdkf",
        "distance" : 20,
        "angle" : 45
    }   
}
```

translates to

```
public class item {
    public status status { get; set; }
    public response response { get; set; }
}
public class status {
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
public class response {
    public string token { get; set; }
    public int distance { get; set; }
    public int angle { get; set; }
}
```

but in this case item is anonymous (which is still valid)

and then use it like this:

```
var deserializedJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<item>(JsonString);
```

Comment: So calling this function will automatically associate each class and member with the appropriate key:value pair?

Comment: @brian calling this function will correctly deserialize the json object into a c# object, yes. That other thing you said is not correct. I'm not keeping a key value pair here. If you need to return a list of KVP then you will probably need something else.

Comment: I don't need to return KVP, I was just referring to the particular KVPs in the JSON string. Pardon my novice terminology :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrapper around the status anad response, so you need that wrapper class represented in some way, if you want to take the easy path. If you don't want to automagically deserialize, you can take control and avoid the wrapper, but I don't see why this would be a superior option for what you are trying to do. In other words, I am confirming drachenstern's answer, which I also voted on. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the vote of support. :D ~ by the by, how would you name that anonymous wrapper? I'm pretty sure about any name will do, but I tend to send mine back as complex objects, so this seems a little fishy to me.