# How to Convert JSON String into List of <objects>........in windows Phone 7?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

I am getting data from my web service into a JSON string in a file named PreGroup.cs.

In that file I have a object of web service Reference.

Now there is also definitely a method in that PreGroup.cs file and that is:

```
public string LoadAllArticles()
{
    try
    {
        //articles_list = null;
        obj = new GBService.PreGroupbookSreviceSoapClient();
        obj.LoadAllArticlesCompleted += (obj_LoadAllArticlesCompleted);
        obj.LoadAllArticlesAsync();
        obj.CloseAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    //This is string which will be passed to the caller of this method.
    return articles_list;
}
```

and here is the load:

```
void obj_LoadAllArticlesCompleted(object sender, GBService.LoadAllArticlesCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        articles_list = e.Result.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        throw Ex;
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Welcome to Groupbook </br>" + AllArticleData);
    obj.LoadAllArticlesCompleted -= (obj_LoadAllArticlesCompleted);
}
```

Now when I call this method in my windows phone's page "Index.cs" where I want to load all the articles, I am unable to convert that simple string back to the List.

Here is me code of the Index.cs class where I have tried **many** things to deserialize/ parse/etc but I am unable to convert that string into List:

```
private void LoadArticles()
{
    obj = new PreGroupbook();
    string art=  obj.LoadAllArticles();
    // How to convert that string into  List<GB_articles> ?????? I have several ways
    MyArticles.ItemsSource = gb_li;
}
```

And here is the string which I want to deserialize:

```
[{
    "article_id": 1,
    "article_title": "This is Test Article",
    "created_timestamp": "\/Date(1346395093347)\/",
    "modified_timestamp": null,
    "article_category_id": 3,
    "privacy_id": 1,
    "subscribers_count": 51,
    "votes_down_count": 21,
    "article_tag": "My Best C++",
    "votes_up_count": 42,
    "isActive": true
}, {
    "article_id": 2,
    "article_title": "The flying Horse was seen",
    "created_timestamp": "\/Date(1346395104223)\/",
    "modified_timestamp": null,
    "article_category_id": 3,
    "privacy_id": 1,
    "subscribers_count": 51,
    "votes_down_count": 21,
    "article_tag": "My Best C++",
    "votes_up_count": 42,
    "isActive": true
}, {
    "article_id": 3,
    "article_title": "iWatch is just amazing",
    "created_timestamp": "\/Date(1346395105477)\/",
    "modified_timestamp": null,
    "article_category_id": 3,
    "privacy_id": 1,
    "subscribers_count": 51,
    "votes_down_count": 21,
    "article_tag": "My Best C++",
    "votes_up_count": 42,
    "isActive": true
}, {
    "article_id": 4,
    "article_title": "Oh My My....did you see that???",
    "created_timestamp": "\/Date(1346395107890)\/",
    "modified_timestamp": null,
    "article_category_id": 3,
    "privacy_id": 1,
    "subscribers_count": 51,
    "votes_down_count": 21,
    "article_tag": "My Best C++",
    "votes_up_count": 42,
    "isActive": true
}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Harsh - if you're going to edit the question, please try and clean up the **entire** question, not just a simple code format.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116656/too-minor-edit-reason-can-sometimes-be-a-little-contradictory

Comment: Check the related answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6658209/468718

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables ok I will take care of that next time !

Comment: @HarshBaid... I have tried that tutorial too. But its not looking good ...as its not working..because When I debug my project than..it reaches till the line  `List<GB_articles> a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GB_articles>>(e.Result);` and than not notifying anything ..it stops without any error....not even showing any thing...i have placed try catch block alse...

Answer (score 0):

```
var articles  = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Article>>(jsonstr);

public class Article
{
    public string article_id;
    public DateTime created_timestamp;
    public int votes_up_count;
    //other fields.........
}
```

**EDIT**

for WP7 use [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
var articles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Article>>(jsonstr);
```

Comment: not working? What doesn't work? What error do you get? Or Is it somehow too lazy??

Comment: When I debug my project than..it reaches till the line var articles = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Article>>(jsonstr);
 and than not notifying anything ..it stops without any error....not even showing any thing...i have placed try catch block alse..

Comment: Now what is this????
`**Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'PreGroupbook.Services.GB_articles' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.Path '', line 1, position 1`.**

Comment: @SoftBuildersPk don't deserialize to **PreGroupbook.Services.GB_articles**, deserialize to **List<Article>** in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the implementation descrived in Test Web application (in my local) please reproduce it in your local. Should work then.

```
string testJson = "[{\"article_id\": 1,\"article_title\": \"This is Test Article\",\"created_timestamp\": \"\\/Date(1350738778146)\\/\",\"modified_timestamp\": \"\\/Date(1350738778146)\\/\",\"article_category_id\": 3,\"privacy_id\": 1,\"subscribers_count\": 51,\"votes_down_count\": 21,\"article_tag\": \"My Best C++\",\"votes_up_count\": 42,\"isActive\": true}]";
articles = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Article>>(testJson);
gvArticles.DataSource = articles;
gvArticles.DataBind();
```

**Article class**

```
public class Article
{
    public int? article_id { get; set; }
    public string article_title { get; set; }
    public DateTime? created_timestamp { get; set; }
    public DateTime? modified_timestamp { get; set; }
    public int? article_category_id { get; set; }
    public int? privacy_id { get; set; }
    public int? subscribers_count { get; set; }
    public int? votes_down_count { get; set; }
    public string article_tag { get; set; }
    public int? votes_up_count { get; set; }
    public bool? isActive { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Common Dude....I am using this in Windows phone Application....and there JavaScriptSerializer is not know by compiler

Comment: Well the clr object is setup as I have mentioned in the answer, now remains deserializing the string for that you can use json.net as seen here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241049/deserializing-json-in-windows-phone-7-with-json-net or check http://www.ben.geek.nz/2010/06/proper-json-deserialization-in-windows-phone-7/ blog article or find some api that will deserialize the string in windows phone 7.

Comment: Nothing worked yet for me , but now I have converted That Json string into XML string and Now I want to Convert back that XML string into List of Objects...because I thought this might be an easy option....any further help??? Guys please post answers related to the Windows Phone 7 .... Thanks and Regards

Comment: @softbuilders if u have XML data then u can directly bind it to ItemSource in XAML, please refer some XML binding for XAML apps. (posted frm mobile)

Answer (score 0):

First you convert class from json string.for that simply you copy jsonstring and paste it to WWW.json2c#.com and you will get class .put that class in you project .and than deserilazed it with :

```
 var editdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
```